# Translations for the gender category

Tags: javascript, translation

I'm working on a dataset and I'm looking for a javascript library that can translate the categories "Male" and "Female" to different languages. I don't need to worry about nonbinary genders.

For example: ChineseSimplified: "Male" -> "男".

I haven't been able to find anything in npm. I've tried using google translate but it's giving me back things like "男性" which is not what I want.

The languages I need are: ChineseSimplified, ChineseTraditional, Spanish, English, German, French, Indonesian, Russian, Japanese, Korean, Portuguese, Thai, Vietnamese.

Comment: Why not define them yourself? 2 words in 13 languages is not a lot or did I missunderstand what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I will probably have to do that. I figured someone might have already made a library for this and I didn't want to go through the trouble of figuring out which translations are correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  ChineseSimplified: '男',
  ChineseTraditional: '男',
  German: 'Männlich',
  English: 'Male',
  Spanish: 'Masculino',
  French: 'Homme',
  Indonesian: 'Pria',
  Japanese: '男',
  Korean: '남성',
  Portuguese: 'Masculino',
  Russian: 'мужчина',
  Thai: 'ชาย',
  Vietnamese: 'nam'
}

{
  ChineseSimplified: '女',
  ChineseTraditional: '女',
  German: 'Weiblich',
  English: 'Female',
  Spanish: 'Femenino',
  French: 'Femme',
  Indonesian: 'Perempuan',
  Japanese: '女',
  Korean: '여성',
  Portuguese: 'Feminino',
  Russian: 'женский',
  Thai: 'ผู้หญิง',
  Vietnamese: 'nữ'
}
```

probably good enough